# how to prove the differential version of jordan curve theorem

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, analytic-geometry

If we have smooth embedding $\phi:s^1\rightarrow R^2$ ,how to prove that the interior $\Omega$ is smooth homoemorphism to $D^2$  .

I can prove this question use Jordan curve theorem and Riemann mapping theorem these two big theorem.But I'm trying to find a more element method and can be  extend to other dimenssion.
I think this question is equivalent to find a smooth function $f|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ with single maximum point and no minimum point in $\Omega$ .I have tried to use some elliptic pde method to solve this problem but I failed.

Comment: I'm somehow confused by the following: do you already know that $\phi(s^1)$ divides $R^2$ into two parts? You're referring to $\Omega$ as if this was something already given.

Comment: yes， I know it can be concluded by homology theory.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming you were trying to prove the differential Jordan theorem without the heavy machinery of the topological Jordan theorem (which should be possible, anyway). So $\Omega$ is a priori homeomorphic to $D^2$ and the goal is to get a diffeomorphism?

Comment: yes，the goal is to get diffeomorphism and the method can be extend to higher dimension.

Comment: Look at the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem in Guilllemin and Pollack.

Comment: As a PDE approach, you could use $\Delta f - |\nabla f|^{-2} \langle D^2 f \nabla f, \nabla f \rangle + 1 = 0$ (i.e. equation (1.5) in [A deterministic-control-based approach to
motion by curvature](https://www.math.nyu.edu/~kohn/papers/kohn-serfaty-cpam.pdf) by Kohn-Serfaty), which describes the curvature flow of $\phi$. This flow deforms $\phi(s^1)$ to a point without causing intersections on the way.

Comment: By the way, the statement that the interior is homeomorphic/diffeomorphic to $D^2$ is known as the Schönflies theorem.  The Jordan curve theorem is simply the statement you seem to already know, namely that the curve separates the plane into an interior open subset (connected and bounded) and an exterior open subset (connected and unbounded.